# Apollo/graphQL: How to use optimistic UI for a mutation of a nested react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-apollo, next.js, optimistic-ui

As shown below I'm getting my data in my nextJS application in the `pages/article.js` using a graphQL query.
This data is passed down to another react component, which gives me a list of checkboxes.

Selecting a checkbox is calling a mutation to store the ID of the selected checkboxes in the DB.
To get the content updated, I'm using `refetchQueries` to call the **main query** again, which will pass the data down to the current component.

So far everything is working. Now I would like to get this stuff realtime using optimistic UI - which makes me some problems...

Replacing the `refetchQueries` with

```
update: (store, { data: { getArticle } }) => {
  const data = store.readQuery({
    query: getArticle,
    variables: {
      id: mainID
    }
  })
  console.log(data)
}
```

runs me to the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined` which comes from `readQuery`.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong. And this is just the first part to get optimisic UI..

**pages/article.js**

```
import Article from '../components/Article'

class ArticlePage extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps (context, apolloClient) {
    const { query: { id }, req } = context
    const initProps = { }

    // ...

    return { id, ...initProps }
  }

  render () {
    const { id, data } = this.props
    const { list } = data
    return (
      <Article
        mainID={id}
        list={list}
      />
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
  withData,
  graphql(getArticle, {
    options: props => ({
      variables: {
        id: props.id
      }
    })
  })
)(ExtendedArticlePage)
```

**components/Article.js**

```
import { getArticle } from '../graphql/article'
import { selectMutation } from '../graphql/selection'

export class Article extends Component {
  checkboxToggle (id) {
    const { mainID, checkboxSelect } = this.props

    checkboxSelect({
      variables: {
        id
      },
      refetchQueries: [{
        query: getArticle,
        variables: {
          id: mainID
        }
      }],

    })
  }

  render () {
    const { list } = this.props
    return (
      list.map(l => {
        return (<Checkbox onClick={this.checkboxToggle.bind(this, l.id)} label={l.content} />)
      }
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(selectMutation, { name: 'checkboxSelect' })
)(Article)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a variable shadowing issue in your update code, it seems that you're using the same name `getArticle` for both your query and the mutation result nested in `data`.

This is why your call to `readQuery` fails, the `query` params you need to provide resolves to the mutation result and not the actual query, hence the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined`.

You just need to name your query with another identifier like `getQueryArticle`.

Comment: Oh, understand. Thank you for that. Could you please explain the second parameter of the new update function? (`{ data: { getArticle } }`). This seems to have no content in my case, so I think it is named wrong and I'm asking myself if I do really need it...

Comment: Sure you can debug it yourself rewriting your update func like this:
`update: (store, { data }) => { console.log(data); }`
You'll figure out that there's a field in the data object usually named after your mutation that contains the mutation result.